# Addition with NULL values across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, addition

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    SumCol
  4       9     NULL      13
NULL      8       2       10
  8       3     NULL      11
NULL      5       5       10
```

I have a table populated with columns Col1, Col2, and Col3, and I am trying to create a new column, SumCol. I know addition with NULL values is annoying so I appreciate any help

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use below queries in sql-server

```
select id, col1, col2, col3, (coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) + coalesce(col3, 0)) total
from @tbl
```

OR

```
select id, col1, col2, col3, (ISNULL(col1, 0) + ISNULL(col2, 0) + ISNULL(col3, 0)) total
from @tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple by using XQuery or `COALESCE()`.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES
(  4 , 9, NULL),
(NULL, 8,   2 ),
(  8 , 3, NULL),
(NULL, 5,   5 );
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3
    , x.value('sum(/root/*/text())', 'INT') AS Summary
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(x);
```

**SQL #2**

Based on the @DaleK's advice, a most common solution is below.

```
SELECT * 
    , Summary = COALESCE(Col1,0) + COALESCE(Col2,0) + COALESCE(Col3,0) 
FROM @tbl;
```

**SQL #3**

A generic way tailored towards Col1, Col2, ..., ColN scenario.

```
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3
    , x.value('sum(/root/*[not(local-name()="ID")]/text())', 'INT') AS Summary
FROM @tbl AS p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE c.ID = p.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+------+------+---------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Summary |
+----+------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | 4    |    9 | NULL |      13 |
|  2 | NULL |    8 | 2    |      10 |
|  3 | 8    |    3 | NULL |      11 |
|  4 | NULL |    5 | 5    |      10 |
+----+------+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: I must be missing something, isn't it as simple as `SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, coalesce(Col1,0)+coalesce(Col2,0)+coalesce(Col3,0) SumCol FROM @tbl`?

Comment: @DaleK, there are many ways to skin a cat. Specially for col1, col2, ..., colN scenario.

Comment: Well yes, but wouldn't one choose the least complex, most performant method?

Comment: @DaleK, for the colN scenario it will become too verbose.

Comment: True, but OP didn't ask for more than 3 cols.

Comment: @DaleK, I assumed it is a minimal repro pertaining to the columns count. It looks like a school exercise. I also noticed that the OP never accepted a single answer.

Comment: Well thats why you would normally avoid answering such a poor question. But if you feel inclined to maybe add both solutions to cover your bases.

Comment: Adding SQL #4 (just for fun):  select *,  
(select sum(st.cc) from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3)) st (cc)) as tsum
from @tbl t

Answer (score 1):

**A computed column is often easier**, if you want that calculation to always be available to anyone who queries the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD COLUMN SumCol AS ISNULL(Col1, 0) + ISNULL(Col2, 0) + ISNULL(Col3, 0);
```